# generating access token in Cloud Functions for service-service auth

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to establish service-service authentication between Cloud Functions and Cloud Endpoints.

I am trying to send a HTTP request inside a Firebase Cloud Function to my API running on Google App Engine and managed by Google Cloud Endpoints.

As stated in google docs, the service account that Firebase Cloud Functions uses is ____@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com

I added that issuer in the security definition of my openAPI config(cloud endpoints). However, I could not find a way to create an access token in Cloud Functions of that service account.

**How can I generate an access token in Cloud Functions to authenticate itself to Cloud Endpoints?** How am I supposed to sign the JWT on cloud functions to [request an access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatingjwt)?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_credentials_on_compute_engine_kubernetes_engine_app_engine_flexible_environment_and_cloud_functions).